# How to compute the sum $\sum_{r=0}^n \frac{(-1)^r}{{n \choose r}}$

Tags: binomial-coefficients

Consider the sum
$$\sum_{r=0}^n \frac{(-1)^r}{{n \choose r}}.$$
I know the sum is zero when $n$ is odd (pretty simple).
The sum is $2-\frac{2}{2 + n}$  when $n$ is even.

Can somebody provide a proof in the even case?
Thanks

Comment: if $n$ is odd then $$sum=\sum_{r=0}^n \frac{(-1)^r}{{n \choose r}}=\sum_{r=0}^{[n/2]} (\frac{(-1)^r}{{n \choose r}}+\frac{(-1)^{n-r}}{{n \choose {n-r}}})=\sum_{r=0}^{[n/2]} (\frac{(-1)^r}{{n \choose r}}-\frac{(-1)^{r}}{{n \choose {r}}})=\sum_{r=0}^{[n/2]} 0=0$$

Answer (score 5):

Start by writing ${1/ {n\choose r}}=(n+1)\int_0^1 u^r(1-u)^{n-r}\,du.$
Multiplying by $(-1)^r$ and adding over $r$ gives
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{r=0}^n (-1)^r/{n\choose r}
&=&(n+1)\int_0^1 \sum_{r=0}^n (-u)^r(1-u)^{n-r}\,du\\
&=&(n+1)\int_0^1 [(1-u)^{n+1}+(-1)^nu^{n+1}]\,du\\
&=&{n+1\over n+2}(1+(-1)^n).
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: how you remember that $ 1/{{n\choose r}}=(n+1)\int_0^1 u^r(1-u)^{n-r}\,du $?

Comment: It comes from the Beta function: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function

Comment: thank you! I proof this identity by induction... are there another way?

Comment: Hmmm... I'm not sure.